# Как сделать сопротивление при touch управление слайдером

Tags: javascript, jquery

Всем доброго времени суток.

Суть вопроса в следующем. Есть слайдер, который состоит из списка `ul` в котором любое количество `li`, в которых есть какой-то контент.

Управляется `touch` и `mouse` событиями. Как сделать, если перед (назад листаем) или после (вперед листаем) нет предыдущего или следующего слайда, сопротивление (если я правильно это называю).

Если кто нибудь делал уже такие вещи помогите советом. Или где почитать подробнее можно об этом.

Answer (score 0):

Проще всего будет использовать уже готовый слайдер.
http://meandmax.github.io/lory/